# EV3 SPIK3R on Mission 5 just keeps backing up

Tags: ev3

I completely built the Mindstorms EV3 Spik3r. Missions 1-4 worked fine. However, with mission 5, and using the pre-made program, the robot just keeps backing up, instead of facing the bug, shooting it and then moving towards it. I put the 'bug' right in front (5cm) of the robot, and it backs up. I put the bug a bit further (50cm) in front, and the robot still keeps backing up.

If I hold the bug in my hand and move it to about 5 cm from the sensor, above it (like a 45-degree angle), then the sensor detects the bug, and the robot shoots at it and then tries to crush it. But it seems pretty flaky.

Is there an EV3 program I could download to help me debug this, or at least understand what's going on? Perhaps a program that shows the ultrasonic sensor's reading in real-time on the brick so I can move the bug around and see what the readings are?

What else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps a program that shows the ultrasonic sensor's reading in real
>   time on the brick so I can move the bug around and see what the
>   readings are?

You can easily view the ultrasonic sensors readings in real time. To do so, turn on your EV3 brick, navigate to the 'Brick Apps' tab (second from the right) and launch the 'Port View' application.

Use the EV3 buttons to find the port which your ultrasonic sensor is connected to. The ultrasonic sensor value should be shown.

Comment: By "real-time," Jimmy probably means while the program is running, not the opposite. He will need to make a program that shows these statistics and add it to the pre-made mission 5 program.